# How would I modify this Alfresco query to display folders as well as documents

Tags: drupal, alfresco, cmis

I'm using the Drupal modules "CMIS API" and "CMIS VIEWS" and I'm, trying to list both documents and subfolders but currently it's only showing the documents. I'm doing this by using the GUI that is included with the CMIS Views module as I have no experience with Alfresco. I select my folder that contains both subfolders and documents, yet only the documents display.

This is the query that the module is running against Alfresco :

`select d.*, t.* from cmis:document as d join cm:titled as t on d.cmis:objectid = t.cmis:objectid where in_folder(d, 'cf6bfb20-5499-46c4-92ea-abe39cf9e405')`

How would I modify this query to show the folders as well?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMIS standard implements `cmis:document` and `cmis:folder` as two of four `cmis:baseTypeId` objects. Even if CMIS has JOIN as one of the SQL statements, Alfresco implementation currently does not support JOIN except as an extension to support aspects. This extension is Alfresco specific.
This means that you can't achieve something like:

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:folder INNER JOIN cmis:document etc
```

as Alfresco will not recognize the query.
What you can do is run two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:folder F WHERE IN_TREE(F, 'workspace://SpacesStore/cf6bfb20-5499-46c4-92ea-abe39cf9e405')
```

and

```
    SELECT * FROM cmis:document F WHERE IN_TREE(F, 'workspace://SpacesStore/cf6bfb20-5499-46c4-92ea-abe39cf9e405')
```

where `workspace://SpacesStore/cf6bfb20-5499-46c4-92ea-abe39cf9e405` should be the nodeRef of your parent folder.

[Here](http://www.alfresco.com/cmis) you can access the alfresco cmis browser and web app (click on the [Web Scripts CMIS Browser](http://cmis.alfresco.com/service/cmis-browser-app/connections) link, access with admin/admin, and click on the `query` link. This will help you use and test your queries.

Another solution is to use native alfresco cmis web scripts (or develop one by yourself) through:
[CMIS getFolderChildren](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Web_Scripts_Reference#Get_Folder_Children_.28getChildren.29). Instead of using a SQL-based query you can call a web service and access whatever you need in your repo.

Hope it helps.

Cheers